# How to configure unique key with multiple field in SimpleSchema

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I'm using SimpleSchema in meteor app. Now I need to define unique key with multiple field. In a Collection I have field like

```
servingDate, vanId, timeSlot
```

I need to make a unique with those three fields. Is there any possibilities to do in SimpleSchema ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that from with a simple schema configuration. Your only valid option is:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  MyCollection._ensureIndex(
    {servingDate: 1, vanId: 1, timeSlot: 1},
    { unique: true }
  );
}
```

Comment: The code works fine and duplicate keys cause a validation error on save.  How do you set the custom validation error message?